using ajax with asp.net core mvc .NET 8 in visual studio 2022
I have a view that shows information from a sql tabel that I inserted in to a local DataTable I want to create a button that filters what is shown with ajax
this is the loop where the information from the server is shown
@model System.Data.DataTable



@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="BluePrint">
        @* <div id="BluePrintWrapper"> *@


        <img src="~/Images/@Model.Rows[i]["ThumbNail"]" class="BluePrintBild" />

        <p id="HouseName">@Model.Rows[i]["HouseName"]</p>

        <p id="Mod">Vanilla</p>

        <p id="Difficulty">MEDIUM</p>

        <img src="~/Images/STEN.jpg" id="Sten" />

        @if (Convert.ToBoolean(Model.Rows[i]["Featured"]) == true)
        {
            <p id="FeatureText">Featured</p>
        }

        @if (Convert.ToInt32(Model.Rows[i]["IsLiked"]) != 0)
        {
            <img src="~/Images/Liked.png" id="Like" />
        }
        else
        {
            <img src="~/Images/NotLiked.png" id="Liked" />
        }

        <p id="Price">@Model.Rows[i]["Price"]$ / 1 FREE PER MONTH</p>
        <p id="Size">@Model.Rows[i]["HouseSize"] Blocks</p>
        <p id="Floors">@Model.Rows[i]["Floors"] Floors</p>
        <p id="File">@Model.Rows[i]["FileSize"]MB</p>
        @*  </div> *@

    </div>


I have also created a DbContext I don't know if this is needed though:
namespace OoOoO.Utilities
{
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using OoOoO.Models;

    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<BluePrintModel> BluePrintModel { get; set; }
    }
}


I have tried looking at multiple videos and blogg posts i also asked chat gpt nothing looked right and i just have no idé on where to begin any help would be apreciated

What do you want to achieve with the button? What have you tried and what are the obstacles?

It looks like you have thrown bunch of disconnected pieces of code, from different sources into the question. What is $('DataTable').DataTable? What is @Url.Action("GetUserSubmited") pointing to? Why are you giving code of Shop method that has nothing to do with the rest of the code?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

to amswer tje questions above what i want to achive is change the data that is sent to the view in the action i have this "return View(dataTable);" and this is what I want to change.
The obstacle is that i really have no idé of how anything works and I don't know what to do. Im sorry that this is abstract but this is a bit conffusing to me
And the second comment that is from chat gpt i where planing to not to send it i forgot to remove it before i copied the code so I don't have any ajax yet as like staded I am confused.
I gave Shop Method to show everything about the view

Still its not clear what you are trying to achieve or what's your issue. Are you trying to call ajax request or you would like to filter using ajax request? Please share relevant smaple or details.
